# Google analytics tracking js code not working in React

Tags: reactjs, google-analytics

I have a react website and in my html template I put the google analytics tracking code snippet.

The tracking works on my local (so I can actually see my dev session in GA console) but it doesn't work after I deploy to cloud. Here how my template looks like and react just render the root div.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    ...
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="root" />
  </body>

  <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
  <script async src="GA link..."></script>
  <script>
    GA tracking code...
  </script>

</html>
```

My site is [here](http://npgee.com). You can see from the source code the tracking code is there. However current session just doesn't show up in GA.

Comment: Try putting the script within the `<body>` tag.

Comment: Just tried that didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

When I go to your site I see calls going out to Google Tag Manager and Google Analytics and Doubleclick.

Maybe you have a script blocker (uBlock Origin, Noscript, ...) disabled on localhost but active on the production site?

Comment: It's strange.. I don't have any script blocker. Also tried with different browser..

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it eventually. Regenerate another project in GA and use the new project worked for me. Maybe it was something mess up with my old project setup.